# Mirroring MS Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

I did some research into this and couldn't quite find an answer.

The company I currently work for has three Access databases they currently use, that are fairly small, and I would like to combine them all into one database. In addition, they have some data that only lives in Excel spreadsheets that should be put in Access.

So what I am wondering is if there is a way I can link these three databases to a new "master" database, that will automatically update the new "master" database when they are making changes to the old ones. Trying not to upset their workflow. However, it would be great if the additions I need to make, are not reflected in the databases they are using.

That way I can work on the new database and add the information that only exists on Excel. Make sense? Not quite sure how to accomplish this.

EDIT: Sorry meant to include the version of Access is 2013.

Comment: Not sure if this can be done with MSAccess, because it wasn't meant for that. Maybe, what you can do it's an ETL, that will run once a day, extracting and consolidating the data into a master, that perhaps can be another MSAccess, or why not, a MySQL/PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are all the users and those Excel and Access files on the same LAN?

Comment: Why not import all databases and spreadsheets into one central master database and in the old databases link the master database with [Linked Table Manager](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2013.php)? This way all data is real-time and intact.

Comment: My concern is that it is bi-directional. If I am adding data to their tables, but don't want them to see it just yet. Also, I could link just for importing, break link, then reestablish link to update again and I think it would erase what I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and the way I solved this was to build the master database in PowerPivot(64bit) - which is a free Excel add-in & easily connects to Access & Excel. The PowerPivot(64bit) engine is pretty speedy will automatically handle data refreshes as more data is added or altered in the other databases. Hope this helps.